# EL1008E:(pos 5): Property or field 'customerid' cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.LinkedHashMap' - maybe not public?

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I am trying to iterate list and display values in thymeleaf but i am getting below Error

`Exception processing template "customers/Customers": Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "list.customerid" (customers/Customers:94)
EL1008E:(pos 5): Property or field 'customerid' cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.LinkedHashMap' - maybe not public?`

```
List<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
List<CustomerAccounts> acountsList = custService.findCustomer(mobilenumber, accountnumber); 
    System.out.println("acountsList size:-"+acountsList.size());
    if(acountsList.size() != 0){
        for(CustomerAccounts custAccounts :acountsList){
            DcbCustomerAccount accountMaster = custService.findAccountMaster(custAccounts.getMobilenumber().substring(2), custAccounts.getAccountNumber());
            Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
            if(accountMaster !=null){   
                System.out.println("Customer Id:"+accountMaster.getId().getCustomerid());
                map.put("customerid", accountMaster.getId().getCustomerid());
                map.put("name", custAccounts.getName());
                map.put("accountNumber", custAccounts.getAccountNumber());
                map.put("mobilenumber", custAccounts.getMobilenumber());
                map.put("createdDate", custAccounts.getCreatedDate());
                map.put("status", "Activated");
            }
            list.add(map);
        }       
        System.out.println("List Size:-"+list.size());
        model.addAttribute("acountsList", list);        
    }

<tr th:each="list,iterStat : ${acountsList}">
                                <!-- <td th:text="${list.id}">CustomerID</td> -->
                                <td th:text="${list.customerid}">CustomerID</td>
                                <td th:text="${list.name}">Customer Name</td>
                                <td th:text="${list.accountNumber}">Account Number</td>
                                <td th:text="${list.mobilenumber}">Mobile Number</td>
                                <td th:text="${list.createdDate}">Created Date</td>
                                <td th:text="${list.status}">Created Date</td>

                            </tr>
```

I am trying to put values in map and add to list. Finally list object return is `model` attribute.
Whats wring in my code?

Comment: Probably you are operating on wrong types here. Your final list that you put in the model by line `model.addAttribute("acountsList", list);` is a List of Maps. In your iteration you are accessing it like you are accessing `List<CustomerAccounts>`